# SEHException when debugger is attached

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging

This problem is rather complicated and I'm not sure about how to tackle it. I get the following exception when I start my application.

```
[FATAL] Unhandled exception. EXCEPTION OCCURRED:System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException External component has thrown an exception. Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr)
[FATAL] Last Win32 error code: 00000006; Last HRESULT: 80070006
```

This only occurs when I run the debugger. If I start the application without a debugger, then it never throws an SEHException. As another fact, when I continue it does pop up again in Visual Studio and then exits the application.

I have now managed to narrow it down to this:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
InternalDispatcher = new WpfDispatcher(dispatcher);
```

It does occur right after the constructor call of *WpfDispatcher*.

```
internal WpfDispatcher([NotNull] Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    _dispatcher = dispatcher ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dispatcher));
}
```

I don't see why this happens, though. The `WpfDispatcher`-class is only a wrapper which allows me to use either WinForm or WPF to dispatch, depending on the selected compatibility mode.

And why is this only happening with an attached debugger? The code exists for a long time already and this started to happen only recently...

Is there any way to narrow it down? I just don't get why this happens.

PS: Just checked the threads when this happens and it seems like this exception originates from the GC Finalizer Thread:

```
Not Flagged >   4628    2   Worker Thread   GC Finalizer Thread mscorlib.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.ReleaseHandle   Highest
```

PS2: Activating the native debugger, I get this (slightly) more detailed exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0xFE58917A in Lab.Wpf.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.
```

Comment: Microsoft is very, very worried about this mishap.  Handles have a very nasty malware exploit angle called a "handle recycle attack".  So when the kernel sees that you attached a debugger and you are trying to close a handle that is already closed then it wants to tell you about it.  Why this happened is of course not obvious from the question.  Hey, maybe you are being attacked :)

Comment: Is there any way to find out which handle it is? I don't think that I'm being attacked. Is there anything I can do? This way I can't develop any further since debugging ends in the application exiting ....